# Java - Class Cast Exception using Generics and Lists

Tags: java, list, generics

So I'm trying to create a method which will return a List of any type.
This is my method:

```
    public <T> List<T> mapResponse(Response response){
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //String responseString;

        if (response != null) {
            String responseString = response.getBody();

            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                list = objectMapper.readValue(responseString, new TypeReference<List<T>>() {
                });
            } else {
                log.error("Response status code: {} Response : {}", response.getStatusCode(), responseString);
                throw new BadRequestException(responseString);
            }
        } else {
            log.error("Response from service is null");
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(ResponseIsNull);
        }

    return list;
}
```

When I try to iterate trough the list I get java.lang.ClassCastException.

```
  List<Transaction> list = mapResponse(Response response);
  for (Transaction transaction : list) {
            log.info(transaction.toString()); }
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!